# Using TimeProfiler from Instruments against ios5.1 device from Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, instruments

I've just upgraded to Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.6 but have kept my phone on iOS 5.1 to ensure I can test my apps are backward compatible. I'd like to profile them using Instruments' TIme Profiler but I don't get any details when attaching to the app running on the device. Doing the same procedure works fine with the simulator thought. I Select my device as the target, "Build for Profiling" then "Profile", choose "Time Profiler" and the app starts on the device but I don't get any data at all, only a few little black flags to show low memory warnings. If I do the same thing targeting the simulator I get lots of data in the Call Tree panel. Is it not possible to Time Profile apps on devices? I think I have before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to Time Profile apps on devices, but you might have unearthed an issue with Xcode 4.6 /iOS5.1 / device

```
  instument:          Leaks           Time profiler

  device:
  iPad mini/iOS6.1     YES              YES
  iPhone4S/iOS5.1      YES              IT DEPENDS...
  iPhone3GS/iOS6.1     YES              YES
  simulator/iOS5.1     YES              YES
```

"IT DEPENDS..."

...on whether you want your profile data live: the data seems to get recorded but you won't see it while the profiler is running. When you STOP, the call tree and samples list appears. Sometimes you have to do this twice to get a full list of samples (the first time you just get one sample)

This doesn't seem like something you'd want to rely on...

*update*

The same behaviour is exhibited under OSX 10.7/XCode4.4 and OSX 10.6.8/XCode4.2 so nothing seems to have changed. In fact the *live* use of Time Profiler on a device seems to be a new feature with iOS6+

Comment: Damn. It just so happens I'm on an iPhone4S. Where did you get that list from?

Comment: @Craig - I tested those combinations just now. It seems to be the same for XCode 4.5.2 - but I certainly _was_ able to time profile OS5.1 on 4S sometime in the past.

Comment: @Craig, see my update - this appears to have always been the behaviour, what's new is live Time Profiler updates under iOS6+

Comment: I dont have it with any of my devices (4,4gs,5 running iOS 5 / 6 on xcode 4.5 / 4.6)

Comment: @Daij - ok that's weird - did you say you are on 10.7?